# What is the TC30?

Tags: tron-legacy

According to the Tron wikia, [Castor](http://tron.wikia.com/wiki/Castor) was probably conceived by Kevin Flynn himself "... in the TC30.".

What is the TC30? The wiki does not have a reference and Google was not any help either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears to be a date. The Tron Wiki has an article on a [cycle](http://tron.wikia.com/wiki/Cycle) (a.k.a "Tron Cycle") and uses the abbreviation "TC":

> A Cycle (also known as a Tron Cycle or TC) is a measurement of time used in the Grid.

Thus, [Castor's article](http://tron.wikia.com/wiki/Castor) is saying that Castor was "reputedly designed and created by Kevin Flynn" in the 30th Cycle (i.e. in TC30).

Note that the article says "in TC30", not "in the TC30". The latter might imply a place, but the former implies a time (e.g. one might say "in [the year] 1980").